# Invariants of rational functions?

Tags: elliptic-curves, rational-functions

I have a simple question on rational functions, which appear in the context of rational elliptic surfaces. Let $R$ be a rational functions over say $\mathbb C$, such that $R=P/Q$ with $P$ and $Q$ polynomials. We can study functions $f$ with the property that
$$ R(f(x))=R(x),$$
i.e. $f$ leaves $R$ invariant.

As an example, consider
$$R(x)=\frac{64 \left(4 x^2-3\right)^3}{x^2-1}.$$
Then for
$$f(x)=\frac{2 x \left(x-\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)-3}{2 \sqrt{2 x \left(\sqrt{x^2-1}-x\right)+2}},$$
I find that $R(f(x)=R(x)$.

What is the nature of such functions? Can they be found explicitly for given $R$? I would be grateful for any comments.

Comment: Could you say something about how you got this $f(x)$ for your particular $R(x)$?

Comment: Essentially the idea was that $R(x)=r$ for some fixed $r$ has $n$ solutions, where $n$ is the maximal degree of $P$ and $Q$. Then if $R\circ f=R$, the function $f$ necessarily permutes the solutions to $R(x)=r$. I found $f$ as a map between two solutions. In the context of rational elliptic surfaces, such maps can be found as modular transformation between the solutions. But I doubt this technique is necessary to understand what's going on on the level of rational functions.